# Changing the redirect for default errors

Tags: grails

So, I have a really simple web application I'm making that accomplishes all it's functionality on one page; I don't want any other pages exposed to the user. Yet at the same time, I'd like to take advantage of as much of Grails' built in functionality as possible, including the built in error handling.

I have fields in my domain classes with various constraints on them, i.e. unique: true, blank: false, etc. The error catching works brilliantly like this, and I would like to keep taking advantage of it.

However when one of these errors is thrown, it redirects to the "create" page, and displays flash.message there. What I would like is to redirect back to my index, and show flash.message there.

Is there a place to change this behavior, or will I have to write custom error handling into my controller?

Comment: I feel quite silly. If anyone else sees this, just add a redirect in the section of the controller method that checks to see if it executed successfully. For example, if you're modifying the save method, look for this line:

    if (!voteInstance.save(flush: true)) {

Then just add a redirect under there to where ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define general error pages for different error types in `UrlMappings.groovy` eg:

```
"500"(view: "myErrorView")
 "404"(view: "my404View")
```

You can then throw and log exceptions in your controllers which will then redirect to the 500 error page.